# Раздел "Доступ" в профиле Community♦

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дух-сообщества

Если зайти с модераторскими правами в профиль пользователя [Дух Сообщества♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) на вкладку "Править" и выбрать раздел "Доступ", движок награждает ошибкой и картинкой с котиком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вероятно, стоит вообще скрывать раздел "Доступ" для Community♦.